# MBP Mid-2012 Lion install loops

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install

Background: a week ago I left an airport terminal in a hurry and had to shutdown the MBP with a hard press of the power button.

Once I arrived I was presented with a blinking folder during boot. I  realized either a hard-drive failure had occurred or the HDD cable was fried. I wiped the drive to try on linux mint just to see if I could boot.

This did not help, thus I replaced the cable. This was the original issue but now I'm left with an empty drive.

I can install linux mint and run it without any issues but using internet recovery to install OS X Lion, the installer runs through completely but keeps booting on to the recovery partition after install. I tried this externally with the drive as well without any progress on the issue.

I am asking for help diagnosing the issue as I am currently on the latest linux mint distribution and will provide any necessary feedback requested.